# How detailed questions have to be?

Tags: support, discussion

I want to ask a question like: "How to create a database out of the Tezos Node"
would that be too general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to say unless you can tell us where you are having difficulties specifically.

There is nothing inherently wrong with your question, but I think you will find that Stack Exchange works much better when you have a very specific, applied problem you might encounter in an activity you've already been working on. Stack Exchange wasn't really designed to reproduce an entire section of a hypothetical instruction manual, which may or may not be the case here.

So perhaps, instead of asking broadly:

> "How do I do [process]?"

…you might ask instead:

> "I've been trying to do [process] as described, but I am a bit confused about how to overcome [problem I encountered]."

As the community continues to develop, you'll often start to see terse comments like, ***"what have you tried?"*** It's a bit of shorthand when folks don't feel they should be doing someone else's work from step 1. We try to discourage phrases like "lazy question", but the sentiment being expressed is that authors have to meet us half way before asking someone to help with their problem.

**Please note** that I'm neither embracing nor dismissing your specific question for this site. I'm actually talking over your shoulder to the rest of the community as an opportunity for *everyone* to learn more about these issues as they come up organically. Thank you for your example.

**tldr;** The question is certainly answerable, but sometimes an overly broad question is simply asked too soon for a site like this.

Answer (score 2):

I would say ask your question and usually the way it goes is if it is too general then people will comment to the question itself and ask you to define a bit better what you want to know exactly.

In this particular case i would ask you actually what you mean exactly here ? :) the reason is that the node already maintains its database of chain states so it's not clear what kind of database you have in mind actually!